# How to connect the crystal to generate a simple pulse?

Tags: crystal

I have a 4Mhz (YIC 4.000006 ) crystal. I would like to generate a simple square or sine wave (whichever requires the least components), only for learning purposes, no practical use. I want to be able to see the output on a oscilloscope.

I can't seem to find any tutorials that explain how the crystal is connected/works. I believe I'm using the wrong search terms. Whenever I search for a 'crystal oscillator' I get results of complex schematics (I'm a beginner), but I'm looking for the most primitive way to get some kind of output out of the crystal as I'm trying to learn how it works, but now I'm completely clueless on how to even connect it.

What is the most primitive way using only the standard components to generate any kind of pulse/wave/output from the crystal, so I could pick it up using an oscilloscope? Thanks!

Comment: See: http://www.z80.info/uexosc.htm

Comment: see http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/49251/how-to-connect-a-crystal-oscillator-to-generate-square-wave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't get much simpler than an inverter crystal oscillator:

[image]

Comment: Can this be done without the inverter? The inverter is used as a logic two logic gates? Sorry I'm not familiar with this component as well

Comment: To create an oscillator you need an active device with gain. This is a single simple digital inverter as the gain element. The output invertor is simply to buffer the signal. If you don't know what digital logic is, then you have a more fundamental problem that requires some study.  You could start here: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/00826a.pdf though this may be too advanced.

Comment: @0x29a, as Jack Creasey says, you need a powered circuit and the inverter circuit is a pretty simple one to try. You can get all the parts, and some Veroboard or a breadboard to hold it all, from a high street supplier. Unfortunately, the crystal alone is just a part of the oscillator. Good luck and don't be afraid to have a go :-)

Comment: Thank you very much for the help guys! Ahh every time I try to learn something new I end up missing a component. I tried to build a simple LC Oscillator, but don't had the appropriate size inductor ) Thanks!

Comment: @JackCreasey 'Crystal Oscillator Basics and Crystal Selection' it even has information on non-crystal oscillator circuits, what I was just trying to learning previously, thanks a lot, very useful!

Comment: @JackCreasey  wouldn't it be better with a Non Schmitt trigger for XO, otherwise it oscillates at relaxation rate of 2/Rf*C

Comment: i.e. your schematic shows 2 inverters , but the 1st cannot behave properly with hysteresis. and the 2nd is not necessary to have it either. pls correct schema.

Answer (score -1):

Connect a fast Trise Tfall squarewave generator, frequency at 1MHz or 0.1MHz to one pin of your crystal, and other crystal pin to your scope probe.

How fast a Trise? faster than 1/4 of period of 4MHz , thus faster than 100nanoSecond.

Comment: The OP wanted to use the most primitive means, to see a waveform on the scope. This allows that viewing.